# How do i bindkey the Right Control Key in zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I searched the internet and could not find anybody asking this question. I was annoyed of moving right and the autocomplete `autosuggest-accept` being the same keybind. My closes guesses were

```
bindkey -v '<C-Right>' autosuggest-accept
```

and

```
bindkey '\xffe4' autosuggest-accept
```

but they did not work. How should I go at finding how to do this?

Comment: do you need this to be done "only in zsh while right ctrl still is a modifier for other softwares" ? Or do you consider remapping the right ctrl key everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with **any software/program** running inside a terminal, including `zsh`.

Or at least, I have never seen in any software, either <kbd>Right Ctrl (alone)</kbd> binded to something, or a way to bind it explained in the manual, or an explicit distinction between <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>. If you know one software with this option (working with any terminal), please, let me know.
Software I configured includes : `vim`, `zsh`, `lf`, `fzf`, `tmux`, `htop`, `less`, `most` and `visidata`,
and none talks about what you want. So, if some software can do this in terminal, it's at least extremely rare.
The only times where I have seen something similar to `C-Left, C-Right` (quote from `man tmux` ) are about <kbd>any Ctrl</kbd> pressed with <kbd>left or right arrow</kbd> (It does means <kbd>Left or Right Ctrl</kbd>) : there are also `C-Up, C-Down` while there is not an up/down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on regular keyboard.

---

You can't with `zsh` (assuming `zsh`'s manual is correct) :
after searching `man zshall` (`man zsh` isn't complete), I see there is a <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd> shortcut for :

```
quoted-insert (^V) (unbound) (unbound)
Insert the next character typed into the buffer literally.  An interrupt character will not be inserted.
```

So, now, I try <kbd>any Ctrl + v</kbd><kbd>Left Ctrl + a</kbd>, or <kbd>any Ctrl + v</kbd><kbd>Right Ctrl + a</kbd>, both show me `^A`, that means both put the same char (by checking this with `vim` too, and pressing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, I see that it's the 2nd `ascii` char, with value `0x01`). So `zsh` probably doesn't make any distinction between <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

If I press <kbd>any Ctrl + v</kbd><kbd>Right Ctrl (alone)</kbd>, it does nothing.
Both `vim` and `zsh` tells me the same thing : they don't know when a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed without a key,
while unusual keys like <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (at least unusual in a terminal) give me something :  `^[OP` with `zsh` or `<F1>` with `vim`. Meaning <kbd>F1</kbd> can be recognized with terminals.

---

A shell like `zsh` can run inside `tmux`, and `tmux` has a `send-keys` feature, that doesn't make any distinction between <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>. It means you will not be able to do what you want in the generic case.

To be sure, I also searched in `tmux` source code (I got it with `git clone tmux`), and tried `rgrep -i "ctrl\|control" | grep -i "right\|ctrl.\?r\|r.\ctrl"` to see every time it speaks about the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key, and what I found is :

```
tty-keys.c:134: { "\033Oc", KEYC_RIGHT|KEYC_CTRL },
tty-keys.c:405: { TTYC_KRIT5, KEYC_RIGHT|KEYC_CTRL },
tty-keys.c:406: { TTYC_KRIT6, KEYC_RIGHT|KEYC_SHIFT|KEYC_CTRL },
tty-keys.c:407: { TTYC_KRIT7, KEYC_RIGHT|KEYC_META|KEYC_IMPLIED_META|KEYC_CTRL },
CHANGES:2395:  control the maximum length of left and right components of the 
status bar.
CHANGES:2550:  C- for ctrl keys (^ is still accepted as an alternative).
status.c:1168:  case KEYC_RIGHT|KEYC_CTRL:
```

so, most of them are talking about <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd> and the others aren't relevant.

---

On some terminals like [st](https://github.com/lukesmithxyz/st) (where I can configure any key), on `config.h`, I see code like :

```
{ XK_KP_End,        ControlMask,    "\033[1;5F",    +1,    0},
{ XK_KP_End,        ShiftMask,      "\033[K",       -1,    0},
```

means some stuff is done when you press <kbd>Ctrl + End</kbd> or <kbd>Shift + End</kbd>, and I have seen nowhere any distinction between the left or right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. There is only one `ControlMask`, and also only one `ShiftMask` (so, my answer would be the same if it were about <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys).

I also tried my `rgrep` command on `st` source code, and again, it's talking only about <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd>.

---

I can do this for any other terminal emulator. I think it's enough to consider there is no way to do this in the generic case. Actually, there is a way to get this behavior and to get it only on `zsh` but it's very hard : edit the source code of `zsh`, and of your terminal emulator, and maybe of `xorg`.

---

If you want to change the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>'s behavior, you will need to bind the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> for every software.
See `man xmodmap`, `man setxkbmap` and `man xkeyboard-config` for more informations about keyboard config.

Usually, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are modifiers. It means they are supposed to do something only when you press it with another key.

**note :** there are some rare cases where a key can either act as a modifier or as a key, like :

- some softwares (it includes `libreoffice`) where you will see some letters underlined while you press an <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- `xev` is a tool made to test events, so, it recognizes everything, including pressing an arbitrary key.
- dual function key from [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/) allows some keys to behave like "regular keys" when you type them fast, and like modifiers when you press another key.
- `emacs` has a [key chord](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) feature. It's not exactly about official modifiers (<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> etc.), but it can make a regular key act like a modifier if pressed with some other key in some delay. `emacs` can run outside from the terminal, and you can run a shell inside `emacs`. So, maybe you can :

  - remap the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key to something (let's call it `foo`) everywhere using `setxkbmap` or `xmodmap`.
  - inside `emacs`, remap `foo` back to `right control` using `key-chord` for some parts but not for where you run `zsh`.
  - note that I haven't tested this, and if possible, it's probably not
    simple, but `emacs` is the only "terminal emulator" I know (actually, it's supposed to be a text editor, but it has many features, including running a shell) with a feature close to "something being both a modifier and a regular key".

Comment: It is possible for a terminal emulator to detect that a modifier is pressed alone, and it is possible to distinguish left-ctrl from right-ctrl even if they both map to the same modifier. However, I've never seen a terminal emulator that went through the hoops required to do that. Even Emacs doesn't react to pressing a modifier key alone.

Answer (score 3):

short: you probably can't do that

longer: your mention of `0xffe4` refers to this chunk in `<X11/keysymdef.h>`:

```
/* Modifiers */

#define XK_Shift_L                       0xffe1  /* Left shift */
#define XK_Shift_R                       0xffe2  /* Right shift */
#define XK_Control_L                     0xffe3  /* Left control */
#define XK_Control_R                     0xffe4  /* Right control */
#define XK_Caps_Lock                     0xffe5  /* Caps lock */
#define XK_Shift_Lock                    0xffe6  /* Shift lock */
```

but take note of that ***Modifiers***.  Normally those keys only **modify** other key bindings in X, and do not act alone.  For zsh, bash or any other shell, you need something that acts alone.  You can use `xmodmap` or tinker with *xkb*, by inventing some way to make that key send one or more characters, but without that, the shell will not see anything.

Comment: i am keybinding with zsh, not bash. but if true, that really sucks. would it be possible to do something with pipes?

Comment: no - pipes won't change the result

Comment: Background. You press and release keys, the tiny CPU in the keyboard tells the main CPU "switch 4 went up". The main CPU looks up "switch 4" and says "Ahh, the letter `s`.", or "Ahh, the right hand control key". This lookup can be altered using various tools such as the ones Thomas mentions. You want it to say something like "Ahh, the multimedia stop button". Once you have it as a normal key rather than a "modifier" then you can bind in zsh the "multimedia stop" to do the completion. Whilst it is a modifiers it will not send anything on its own, just modifier others. The clue is in the name.

Comment: @icarus Modifier keys _do_ send something on their own. But the operating system (specifically the X server, when using X) normally filters this out to give modifier keys their normal meaning. An application can still detect modifier press/release events if it wants to (try it with `xev`).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I agree - "You press and release keys, the tiny CPU in the keyboard tells ..." . The question however is being able to access the information from zsh, not from an X application.